# Why the path(enviroment variable) is different between show in the cmd and the system property?(Windows10)

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, environment-variables

Before the question show, i use cmd order `path = %path%D:\test` to add a root in PATH(eniroment variable).When i use cmd order `echo %path%` , it shows:

```
D:\VMware Workstation Pro\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;D:\ffmpeg\bin;D:\mingw64\bin;D:\py3.7\Scripts\;D:\py3.7\;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin;D:\ffmpeg\bin;D:\test
```

But,when i go into the computer property, it shows:

[Computer property shows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9cFn.png)

Obviously, **`D:\Test`** is lost in the the PATH in the computer property of the enviroment value PATH.

I want to know why and how to fix the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why is the path is different in a `cmd` shell and the system property?

If you use `set` to change an environment variable the changes are only valid for the current command shell.

- `set` - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

To make a permanent change use `setx` instead.

- `setx` - Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU)

---

#### Further reading

- [set - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html).
- [setx - Set environment variables permanently](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)

Comment: do you mean like this `>setx path=%path%C:\Test;` I tried this , but it tells me `ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type "SETX /?" for usage.`

Comment: Use `setx path %path%C:\Test`